# Concepts of modifying the element in collection while iterating?

Tags: java

I found this statement if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception. at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html.

I found the concurrent modification is even thrown in below code

```
List<Employee> lista= new ArrayList();
Employee emp1=new Employee();
Employee emp2=new Employee();
Employee emp3=new Employee();
lista.add(emp1);
lista.add(emp2);
lista.add(emp3);
for(Employee emp:lista)
{
emp2.setEmpId(2);
lista.remove(emp2);
}
```

**Question1:- So can i say enhance for loop also uses the fail-fast iterator internally?Though when i execute  below code it works fine**

```
for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
{
Employee empTemp=lista.get(i);
lista.remove(emp2);         
}
```

Question2:- Another question is when statement say

> if a thread modifies a  a collection

**My guess is that modification means here removal or addition not for update of element inside collection  for list interface while it also includes modification of element for set interface . Right? At least the programmes i tried it is the case with them.**

**Edit**

Regarding set i doubt my above statement i.e it throws concurrent modification exception when we try to modify set while iterating.I tried below code but it did not throw any exception

```
HashSet<Employee> set1= new HashSet();
Employee emp4=new Employee();
Employee emp5=new Employee();
Employee emp6=new Employee();
set1.add(emp4);
set1.add(emp5);
set1.add(emp6);


Iterator iter1=set1.iterator();
while(iter1.hasNext())
{
Employee emp12=(Employee)iter1.next();
System.out.println("");
emp5.setEmpId(2);

}
```

**Ideally as per statement if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created at 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html it should throw the concurrent modification exception but it did not . Not sure why?**

Comment: About your example at Question 1: "Though when i execute below code it works fine" Your code is not fine, it is very sick. If you add/remove elements within an indexed for-loop you'll skip some elements or process other elements twice. It's quite a good thing that the iterator throws an exception when you modify a collection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ***Question1:- So can i say enhance for loop also uses the fail-fast iterator internally?Though when i execute below code it works fine***

Yes, thats right. Have a look at the compiled code, with the `javap` command to verify this if you like.

> ***My guess is that modification means here removal or addition not for updation of element inside collection for list interface while it also includes modification of element for set interface . Right? Atleast the programmes i tried it is the case with them.***

Thats right, if you do `emp1.setEmpId(2)` or something similar, the iteration will not fail.

> ***...it should throw the concurrent modification exception but it did not . Not sure why?***

It only throws the exception if you modify *the list*. Keep in mind that the list contains references to objects. If you modify the objects, the references does not change, thus *the list* does not change.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is access by two different threads, there is no danger in modifying the elements within the list. your for does not throw `concurrent modification exception` because you are modifying the elements of the set, not the set itself.